# Scheduled task created in Powershell runs but does not run Powershell script?

Tags: powershell, scheduled-tasks

I have a PS script that runs just fine when run manually, but I am trying to set it to run daily and can't seem to figure out why it won't run. The scheduled task itself will start, but the script doesn't actually seem to run. Any help would be appreciated.

This is what I used to create the scheduled task:

```
$Trigger= New-ScheduledTaskTrigger -At 11:00am –Daily
$User= "NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM"
$Action= New-ScheduledTaskAction -Execute "PowerShell.exe" -Argument "-NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -File G:\Path\ScriptName.ps1"
Register-ScheduledTask -TaskName "TaskyTask" -Trigger $Trigger -User $User -Action $Action -RunLevel Highest –Force
```

Comment: Is `G:` a network drive?

Answer (score 0):

I created a script on my machine @ `C:\test\ScriptName.ps1`

The script is:

`Write-Output "HelloWorld" | Out-File C:\test\HelloWorld.txt`

So I can verfiy it's success by seeing if `HelloWorld.txt` has been created in `C:\Test`

With a tweak to your code to account for the differnce in my script location:

```
$Trigger= New-ScheduledTaskTrigger -At 11:00am –Daily
$User= "NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM"
$Action= New-ScheduledTaskAction -Execute "PowerShell.exe" -Argument "-NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -File C:\Test\ScriptName.ps1"
Register-ScheduledTask -TaskName "TaskyTask" -Trigger $Trigger -User $User -Action $Action -RunLevel Highest –Force
```

The task appears in task scheduler, I run it and `HelloWorld.txt` is created, confirming it works. This to me suggests your script is executing, but maybe not doing what you think.

If you change your script to the same simple script above, does it run?